# Connect Python "Display" with selenium remotly

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-server

I am running Selenium with Display with python 2.7 Ubuntu Server.
I want to connect remotely to see the webdriver from Windows GUI.
Here the code how I initialize the webdriver:

```
self.display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
self.display.start()
self.webdriver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Any idea how to do it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

# now selenium will run in a virtual display. 
# you will not see the browser.
browser = webdriver.selenium()
browser.get('http://www.google.com')
print browser.title
browser.quit()

display.stop()
```

Comment: How you answer here my question? I am asking how to connect from other computer to this display..